# How do I link C code against BoringSSL?

Tags: linux, boringssl

I want to install BoringSSL and link against BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL on Ubuntu.
I couldn't find a simply tutorial of how to do this, the building instructions [here](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md) are vague.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install the language go, if not already done. https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

Example :

```
cd /usr/local/
sudo tar xvf [path-to]/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
cd bin/
sudo ln -s ../go/bin/go* ./
```

2) boringssl, please read README.md, BUILDING.md ...

```
cd boringssl/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ../
make
```

There is no 'make install'. You will have to find `libssl.a` (in build/ssl/) etc. etc., and point to -lssl when using. ( Unfortunately you may already have like `/usr/lib/libssl.so`, which will be linked to, if first in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH ).